# How can I attach a Technic Linear Actuator to a EV3 Medium Motor?

Tags: ev3, technic

I'm pretty new to serious LEGO building (never got past very blocky houses as a kid but got into Technic a couple of months ago) and need to connect a Technic large linear actuator (61927) to a Mindstorms EV3 medium motor for a piece of lab equipment I'm making.

Does anyone have any hints on how to do this? The mounting thing on the linear actuator keeps getting in the way and I'm having trouble getting things to line up.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, let's identify the parts you are trying to attach.

The EV3 medium motor is a pretty accurate description, I'll assume it means [this](http://rebrickable.com/sets/45503-1/ev3-medium-servo-motor-ev3-2013).

The linear actuator is more ambiguous, it can mean both the [smaller](http://rebrickable.com/parts/92693) and the [larger](http://rebrickable.com/parts/61927) variant.

For the smaller one, I'd use two [3 x 3 technic beams](http://rebrickable.com/parts/60484) or two [technic triangles](http://rebrickable.com/parts/99773), one on each side of the motor, attached by technic pins in the first case or half-pins in the second. The axle can be connected via an [axle joiner](http://brickset.com/parts/4512360).

For the larger actuator, I'd use two [quarter brackets](http://rebrickable.com/parts/32249) and two [hybrid beams](http://rebrickable.com/parts/60483) for spacing.

Comment: For the large linear actuator you can also used this specialized part (http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=61905) but unfortunately it's rare and expensive

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question to specify that it's the large linear actuator.

Answer (score 2):

Try this on for size:
[image: Put Together]

Here's an exploded view.

[image: exploded]

This should be compact, robust, let you change gear ratios (so you can get more speed or more torque; the linear actuators are very slow for most applications.), and mount to your system quite well.

Cheers!

Comment: That dropbox link is locked - gives access denied page when trying to view

Comment: Fixed; migrated to brickshelf. Should be live soon...